# Java entity class to a Java Script class

Tags: java, javascript, json, entity

Currently I have an abundant number of java entity classes for which I need a equivalent JavaScript classes. Each of these JavaScript classes will represent a JSON template for a particular category.

The will user will be able to edit this json template(using the json validator http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/).

After editing the json template the user will be able to save the json into a file.

Right now my question is, how should I handle to part where I need to replicate all the java entities into javascript classes.

Comment: Have you checked out serialization libraries like Jackon or Gson?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/), which uses reflection to serialize/deserialize objects to/from JSON and XML.

With JSON ([Example here](http://xstream.codehaus.org/json-tutorial.html) -- see this link for more examples):

```
XStream xstream = new XStream(new JsonHierarchicalStreamDriver());
String json = xstream.toXML(myobject);
```

XStream has a few other features that may be of use to you, like defining class/field aliases, etc. There are other options, like GSON (which many people seem to love and you should check out; I'm just familiar with XStream), as well. Hope that helps.